# Libraries not found when installing from custom profile

Tags: theming, drush, installation-profiles

I've created a custom Drupal installation profile which has the `epsacrop` project included in the makefile and as a requirement in the `.info` file. Also, the `epsascrop` project requires two libraries: `Jcrop` and `json2`. These are both included in my makefile and are placed within the `/profiles/profilename/libraries` directory when running `drush make`. Here the relevant bit from the makefile:

```
libraries[jcrop][download][type] = "git"
libraries[jcrop][download][url] = "https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop.git"
libraries[jcrop][directory_name] = "Jcrop"

libraries[json2][download][type] = "git"
libraries[json2][download][url] = "https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.git"
libraries[json2][directory_name] = "json2"
```

When I run `drush si` to build my site I get an error which indicates that the required libraries are missing, though I can confirm they were correctly placed within `profiles/profilename/libraries`:

> exception 'Exception' with message 'EPSA Crop : Jcrop: Not found
>
> The [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)
>   plugin is missing. [Download](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/downloads/detail?name=jquery.Jcrop-0.9.8.zip&can=2)
>   and extract it in your *sites/all/libraries* directory.
>
> EPSA Crop : json2.js: Not found
>
> The [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) file is
>   missing, you can download it [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and put it
>   in your *sites/all/libraries* directory. Don't forget rename
>   the downloaded folder into json2. At the end, you should have
>   something like this sites/all/libraries/json2' in
>   E:\Projects\amfm_microsites\www1\includes\install.core.inc:773
>
> Stack trace:
>   **0** E:\Projects\amfm_microsites\www1\includes\install.core.inc(471): install_verify_requirements(Array)
>   **1** E:\Projects\amfm_microsites\www1\includes\install.core.inc(339): install_run_task(Array, Array)
>   **2** E:\Projects\amfm_microsites\www1\includes\install.core.inc(77): install_run_tasks(Array)
>   **3** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\includes\drush.inc(719):
>   install_drupal(Array)
>   **4** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\includes\drush.inc(705):
>   drush_call_user_func_array('install_drupal', Array)
>   **5** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\commands\core\drupal\site_install_7.inc(80):
>   drush_op('install_drupal', Array)
>   **6** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\commands\core\site_install.drush.inc(289):
>   drush_core_site_install_version(NULL, Array)
>   **7** [internal function]: drush_core_site_install()
>   **8** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(368):
>   call_user_func_array('drush_core_site...', Array)
>   **9** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(219):
>   _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
>   **10** [internal function]: drush_command()
>   **11** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\includes\command.inc(187):
>   call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
>   **12** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\lib\Drush\Boot\BaseBoot.php(62):
>   drush_dispatch(Array)
>   **13** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php(70):
>   Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
>   **14** C:\Users\aaron.silber\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php(11):
>   drush_main()
>   **15** {main}

I checked the EPSAcrop module and it appears to be using the libraries API correctly, which I believe should look in `profiles/libraries` in addition to `sites/all`.

What's going on here?